# Change taskbar pop-up response time

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, popups

In Windows 7, when you hover over an application icon on the taskbar, a popup appears with an image of the open application in it.  Very useful, but it's kind of slow.
This seems to take about a half second to appear.  Is there any way to reduce the time it takes for the popup to appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Enter registry editor (regedit)
> 2. Navigate to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
> 3. create a new DWORD (32 BIT) named "ExtendedUIHoverTime"
> 4. modify value to desired time (in decimal). *note: typical time is 400 milliseconds*
> 5. restart the system or just explorer *(open task manager, ending the explorer.exe process and then run the "explorer" process)*

[reference site](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/04/28/adjust-longer-or-shorter-and-change-windows-7-taskbar-preview-mouse-hover-delay/)

I get the feeling, however that you will be more annoyed by the fact that they pop up quicker, due to when ever you accidentily roll over them, they will pop up.

Comment: thanks that works perfectly, and it's exactly what I wanted.  I guess time will tell if it begins to annoy me.  :)