# How to change delay time for Aero Peek?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, aero-peek

The Aero Peek feature is incredibly useful for me, but I want it to happen more quickly.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/199933/change-taskbar-pop-up-response-time) question (answered by [KronoS](https://superuser.com/users/47225/kronos)) tells how to change the delay time before the popups occur when hovering over the open application icons on the taskbar.

However, this registry tweak does not work to speed up the desktop peek functionality when the mouse is moved over the 'desktop' area of the task bar.

Any idea how to speed up this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adjust or create this DWORD value:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\DesktopLivePreviewHoverTime
```

log off (or restart explorer.exe) to have it take effect